# databinding multiple fields in UI not updating

Tags: winforms, data-binding, dataset

I have a winform that contains a bindingsource the data source of which is a typed dataset.  I have bound in the designer two text boxes to the same column.  When I update either textbox the DataRow column in the DatSet is correctly updated however the other textbox value on the form is not updated.

What am I missing? How do I get the databindings to update the second textbox?

NOTE: this is a simplified example I need to do this because in the real application because one control is editable by the user the other is the input into a composite control for calculations.

```
// Taken from InitializeComponent()
this.productsBindingSource.DataMember = "Products";    
this.productsBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1;
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.productsBindingSource, "UnitsInStock", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.productsBindingSource, "UnitsInStock", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

// Taken from Form Load Event          
DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter adapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dataSet1.Products);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Typed Data Row class as it is exposed as a partial class by the designer this was fairly straight forward and then set the data source of the bindingsource to be the data row itself.

```
public partial class MyDataRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void AddEventHandler()
    {
        this.Table.ColumnChanged += new System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Table_ColumnChanged);
    }

    void Table_ColumnChanged(object sender, System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(e.Column.ColumnName);
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Code to data bind

```
MyDataRow row = <Get Current Row>;
row.AddEventHandler();
bindingSource1.DataSource = row;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an article on MSDN which might help - see [How to: Ensure Multiple Controls Bound to the Same Data Source Remain Synchronized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404299%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Essentially you need to set up an event handler for the BindingSource's `BindingComplete` event (as you have done, you need to have FormattingEnabled set to True for this to work)

Then, in the BindingComplete event handler, you have this code:

```
    private void productsBindingSource_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the data source has been updated, 
            // and that no error has occured.
            if (e.BindingCompleteContext == BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate && e.Exception == null)
            {
                // End the current edit.
                e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.EndCurrentEdit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as the composite control recalculates which writes a different field back to the data source causing a loop. Also it feels like a bit of a hack to commit the whole row every time you edit a single property.